# Generate all possible pairings

Tags: recursion, pseudocode

This is a problem with recursion that is really been confusing me.

I want to generate all pairings for a range of numbers. They don't have to be all stored, just generated at least once. For example, for `0 1 2 3 4 5` that would be

```
(0 1) (2 3) (4 5)
(0 1) (2 4) (3 5)
(0 1) (2 5) (3 4)
(0 1) (3 4) (2 5)
(0 1) (3 5) (2 4)
(0 2) (1 3) (4 5)
(0 2) (1 4) (3 5)
etc.
```

As you can see, my methodology is to generate a first pair using the first number available to use (in the beginning this is 0, using 0 through 5), iterating through all remaining numbers to create first pairs. Then, for each pair I recurse with the remaining numbers. So if my pair was `0 1` I would repeat the process with `2 3 4 5`.

My problem is I can't figure out how to implement this as a recursive function. I figured out it has to keep a running list of all solutions (so something can be found) while also having to append smaller solutions and combine them. This is too complicated for me to try to imagine, so any help with the method or pseudocode (as simple as possible) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if a recursive function is the right tool to generate pairs. If you had to generate not only pairs but also `(0 2 4 5)` and `(1 3 4)` etc. you could use a recursive function that accepts two arguments: the current permutation and the list of remaining numbers.

Comment: Your rules aren't clear. First, apparently `(0 1) (2 3) (4 5)` is valid, but `(0 1) (2 3) (5 4)` is invalid; correct? Also, `(0 1) (2 3) (4 5)` is unique from `(0 1) (4 5) (2 3)`; correct? What exactly determines valid pairing?

Comment: @user2338816 The first two are actually the same. I made a mistake, the last two you mentioned are also the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode:

```
function allPairingsInSet(Array set) { 

    // assume all elements in set are unique and set.length() >= 2
    if(set.length() == 2) {
        return set;
    }

    // get all pairings containing first element
    Array pairingsWithFirstElement;
    for(int i = 1; i < set.length(); i++){
        pairingsWithFirstElement[i] = (set[0], set[i]);
    }

    // get subsequent pairings excluding the ones with the first element,
    // which we already have; then concatenate the arrays
    return pairingsWithFirstElement + allPairingsInSet(set.subArray(1, set.length()-1));
}
```

With the example set you provided, `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, this method would walk through and find all the pairings that include the first element of the set, `0`.

`[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5)]`

Then it does the same with the subset `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, giving

`[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]`

This continues all the way down to the base case where the set only contains two elements, which can produce only one possible pairing. In this case the base case returns us

`(4, 5)`

Then, in the final return statement, all of these arrays containing pairings are joined together and presented as the final output.